# Making Realm & Unbox play nice

Tags: swift, realm, unboxing

I am learning to parse JSON in Swift, coming from Android/Java, and I am using Unbox by John Sundell to help me with this, which reminds me of GSON.
Reference: [Unbox pod](https://github.com/JohnSundell/Unbox)

I use Realm as a database to store data locally.
Reference: [Realm.io](https://realm.io/products/swift/)

It would be great to find a workflow to parse a class with JSON and save it to Realm. I don't want to have a struct that implements Unboxable AND a class that implements Object (Realm), because then I have to reflect the two. That isn't too much work for my current project, but it is kinda ugly...

Did any of you try a similar workflow?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need two separate types. My suggestion is to create your objects as Swift classes that inherit from Realm's `Object` class, and then also conform them to the `Unboxable` protocol that Unbox offers. (Although the examples on Unbox's page use struct models, there's nothing in the code or documentation that indicates that classes wouldn't work.)

Realm model objects work just like any other classes: in addition to defining whatever properties on the objects you'd like stored in the database, you can also define methods and initializers, and even specify properties that you want Realm to ignore. This allows you to create an object that both serves as a Realm model and also a JSON model compatible with Unbox.

Answer (score 1):

A more concise approach that doesn't require to override required initialisers (based on a [tweet](https://twitter.com/icanzilb/status/730380061447180288) by Marin Todorov):

```
class Car: Object, Unboxable {
    dynamic var vendor: String = ""
    dynamic var modelName: String = ""
    dynamic var electric: Bool = false

    required convenience init(unboxer: Unboxer) throws {
        self.init()
        self.vendor = try unboxer.unbox(key: "vendor")
        self.modelName = try unboxer.unbox(key: "modelName")
        self.electric = try unboxer.unbox(key: "electric")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that works perfectly for me:

```
class ProviderRealm: Object, Unboxable {
    dynamic var identifier: String = "demo"
    dynamic var name: String?
    dynamic var logo: String?

    /// Initializer used for unboxing of JSON string
    required init(unboxer: Unboxer) throws {

        self.identifier = (try? unboxer.unbox(key: "identifier")) ?? "demo"
        self.name = try? unboxer.unbox(key: "name")
        self.logo = try? unboxer.unbox(key: "logo")

        super.init()
    }

    required init(realm: RLMRealm, schema: RLMObjectSchema) {
        super.init(realm: realm, schema: schema)
    }

    required init() {
        super.init()
    }

    required init(value: Any, schema: RLMSchema) {
        super.init(value: value, schema: schema)
    }

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "identifier"
    }
}
```